# Invalid keystore with Google Maps API

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to use the Google Maps API in my Project.
I signed up and got the API key also.

When I run my application now  I'm getting an error "Error generating final archive: Invalid keystore" 
I m really fed up. It is very difficult to use Maps in an application.

Do you know what the problem is in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may have problem with "**`debug.keystore`**",
Go through this example: http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android,

read **Obtaining a Maps API key** paragraph carefully, hope this link useful to you.

Also refer this  [Tutorial](http://codemagician.wordpress.com/2010/05/06/android-google-mapview-tutorial-done-right/) .

Answer (score 0):

Have you been having this problem with your other Android projects? Is your Windows locale NOT set to English, United States? If so, then [this bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=834) may apply to you

If it does not, then please post more info about how you are using the Map in your application. For example, please post the layout code where you use the map, and/or any relavant code. Include the file where you are setting your API key.

Finally, have you tried project->clean? You may want to be sure that your eclipse, your android SDK, and your android eclipse plugin (aka ADT) are all fully up to date before trying to clean the project!

Comment: Now getting on more error.
2010-07-29 12:33:41 - de.vogella.android.locationapi.maps] Could not find de.vogella.android.locationapi.maps.apk!

Comment: vivek - No. I posted an answer and you have not indicated in any way that you tried it. You simply posted another error message. I have no idea how you got that other error. Also, this is a community website. Please don't make inquiries to specific people asking for help. If someone can provide help, they will get back to you in a timely manner. I am sorry if you find this silly of me, but I consider your reply and associated follow up very inconsiderate of my attempt to help you. It looks like Paresh has helped as well, so I wish you the best of luck and hope that his answer works for you